# recieving sqs message body without double quotes

Tags: python, json, amazon-sqs, boto3

Hi I am using boto3 to send and receive sqs message .
I am sending below sqs message .
{"userid":1234,"ml_algorithm_type":1,"file_format":1,"file_path":"leu.gz"}

but while receiving the messages ,I receive below string .
{userid:1234,ml_algorithm_type:1,file_format:1,file_path:leu.gz}

I want to receive exact message  what i have sent .

Comment: I want to receive message exactly what i have sent .

Answer (score 0):

The following test function verifies that in Amazon Simple Queuing Service (SQS), we can receive a message with JSON double quotes.

Note that in the code, it looks like the dictionary has single quotes on the keys and values.  This is fine, as the `json.dumps()` function converts all keys and values to use the JSON standard double quotes.

## test_sqs.py

```
import json

import boto3
from moto import mock_sqs


@mock_sqs
def test_sqs():
    sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', 'us-east-1')
    queue = sqs.create_queue(QueueName='votes')

    queue.send_message(MessageBody=json.dumps({'beer': 'tasty'}))

    messages = queue.receive_messages()
    assert len(messages)
    assert messages[0].body == '{"beer": "tasty"}'  # <- double quotes
```